# How to create a Dataset of String from a Dataset of List of String Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have a Dataset of List of Strings, I need to create anew Dataset from the above having each entry of the list as one line in the new DataSet.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList("abc", "def", "ghi");

Dataset<String> input = spark.createDataset(list,Encoders.bean(String.class));
```

New Dataset is to be like:

```
"abc
def
ghi"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use flatmap to convert the list of String to individual String.
// flatMap each line to words in the line

```
JavaRDD<String> words = input.toJavaRDD().flatMap(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split(",")).iterator());
```